# C++ Pointers and Object Instantiation

Tags: c++, object, pointers, new-operator, instantiation

This works:

```
MyObject *o;
o = new MyObject();
```

And this does not:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
```

Why?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand.  @MPelletier seems to have explained it to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The keyword `new` [returns a pointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It must be assigned to a pointer of an object.

This would also work:

```
MyObject o = MyObject();
```

EDIT:

As Seth commented, the above is equivalent to:

```
MyObject o;
```

The default constructor (i.e. without parameters) is called if no constructor is given.

Comment: I see!  I'm learning C++ after learning Java, so I was under the impression that `new` was required to instantiate an object.

Comment: @Peter, it is required only if you want a pointer. Using `new` allocates memory on the heap, rather than the program's stack. Think of it as the pointer points to something "outside your program". Something "new".

Comment: Actually `MyObject o = MyObject();` is not exactly equivalent to `MyObject o;` although the effect is the same; the former creates a temporary `MyObject` which is default-constructed, then uses the copy constructor to initialise `o` with the temporary, whereas the latter simply default-constructs `o` in-place. Without optimisations, the latter will be faster usually.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck in C++ we change it to "You must `delete` what you `new`"

Comment: @Seth Correct again, I took too great a shortcut on my explanation.

Comment: @SethCarnegie ...although, with newer C++ features, you shouldn't ever explicitly `delete`, rather upon `new`ing immediately assign to a `shared_ptr` or similar, and let that call `delete`.

Comment: @PeterWood true, but that's not what Yoda says. (And btw, with even newer features, you shouldn't even use `new`, but `make_shared` and family.)

Answer (score 5):

Because they're not equivalent. Try:

```
 MyObject* o = new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 4):

`new MyObject()` returns a pointer to an object of type `MyObject`. So really you are trying to assign an object `MyObject*` (yes, a pointer can be considered an object, too). Thus, you have to declare a variable of `MyObject*` or something compatible like `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>`.

The proper initialisation is

```
// in C++03
MyObject* o(new MyObject());

// in C++11
MyObject* o {new MyObject()};
```

While the assignment

```
MyObject* o = new MyObject();
```

is valid as well.